# PDO SELECT Columns correctly

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, pdo

I have googled like crazy and have not found an answer to what I am trying to do. I need to query my DB and get information but also sum one column based on if another column has the same values.

```
    $data = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `name`, SUM(`cost`) FROM `donations` WHERE `name` = `name` ORDER BY `cost` DESC");
    $data->execute();
    $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I need this to add up all of "cost" where the "name" is the same in the column.

Comment: SELECT `name`, SUM(`cost`) FROM `donations` ORDER BY `cost` DESC?

Comment: Use "group by name".

Comment: Are you asking how to sum the `cost` column for all records where the `name` column is not unique?

Comment: @skeggse Sums it up. <-- see what I did there :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `name`, SUM(`cost`) AS `cost` FROM `donations` GROUP BY `name` ORDER BY `cost` DESC";
```

This is outputting the way I want it but I am not sure if it is correct can someone explain what exactly "AS `cost`" is doing?

Comment: The `AS cost` renames the result column. PDO normally would return an unwiedly entry `$row["SUM(cost)"]` because that's specified as SELECT expression. The `… AS …` renames the function call to an alias, and thus returns a tidier result column key.

Comment: You should accept your answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Can not accept my answer until tomorrow but I will.

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `name`, SUM(`cost`) FROM `donations` WHERE `name` = ? GROUP BY name ORDER BY `cost` DESC");
```

Add a `GROUP BY` clause:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Getting SQL error. `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound`

Comment: you need to bind the `?` to a parameter. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: I think what he wants is to get the top donors and not finding how much 1 person donated

Comment: No I want to get the total amount one person donated.

Comment: @JoshuaNightingale so you have some page where you type in a person's name (or other identifier) and you just want to get the total that person has donated along with their name? I recommend you edit the original question to reflect that.